# how to convert pandas groupby output to separate excel sheet?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have created a timestamp of 10 days of hourly data and then create 2 random columns with random values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
timestamp = pd.date_range('01/01/2020 00:00','01/10/2020 23:00', freq = '1H')
arr1 = np.random.randint(100,200,(len(timestamp)))
arr2 = np.random.randint(100,200,(len(timestamp)))
```

the created the `dataframe` of these two `arrays` with `col1` and `col2` as columns and with `timestamp` as an index.

```
dic1 = {'col1':arr1,'col2':arr2}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic1, index=timestamp)
```

After that, I used the pandas `groupby` function to group them by `days` and I wanted to create the excel output of each group ( 10 excel outputs for 10 days).

```
df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))
for idx, i in enumerate(df2):
   df = pd.Dataframe(i)
   df.to_csv(str(idx)+'.csv')
```

but this gives out very strange output, 10 excel files are there but no values in them. Can someone please help?
**Desired output**
for day 1:
[image]

similarly, for every day this type of excel should be generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you iterate a `.groupby`, you get a 2-tuple where the first element is the group key and the second one the group data, so you need something like:

```
df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))
for idx, (_, sdf) in enumerate(df2):
   sdf.to_csv(str(idx) + '.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `for idx, i in enumerate(df2)`, each `i` is a pair `group_key, data`. Try:

```
for g, data in df.groupby(...):
    data.to_csv(str(g) + '.csv')
```

If you really want enumerate:

```
for idx, (g, data) in enumerate(df.groupby(...)):
    data.to_csv(str(idx) + '.csv')
```

Comment: hey this gives an error TypeError: 'ellipsis' object is not callable

Comment: A, I was lazy, you should put `pd.Grouper(freq='D')` instead of the ellipsis. Sorry

Comment: haha... its okay. thank you so much for your help